# Можно ли изменить стиль кнопки в зависимости от валидности инпута чисто на css?

Tags: html, css

Примерный код в html:

```
    <form action="#">
        <label for="email">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" 
             required>
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

Необходимо изменить стиль кнопки, когда пользователь вводит e-mail в поле импута. Можно это сделать на чистом css, без использования js?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только при условии, что `input` и `input[type="submit"]` будут лежать на одном уровне, тогда при помощи `input:valid ~ input[type="submit"]` можно изменять стили кнопки.
Но лучше JS.

```css
.submit {
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: .25em .75em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#email:valid ~ .submit {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
  <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В моём случае так не получится. Там у инпута бордер с градиентом и чтобы его реализовать инпут должен быть завернут в лейбл. По-крйней мере в инете только такой способ отыскался.

Comment: @Lucille, так покажите пример, вдруг есть вариант сделать иначе.

Comment: Если бы я знала, то не спрашивала :) У вас хороший совет, просто в моём конкретном случае с градиентным бордером не получится html написать так, чтобы баттон был на одном уровне с инпутом. Но я запомню, вдруг ещё где понадобится.